# Might a reducing valve reduce pressure further when city water pressure is already low?

Tags: water, pressure

Installed the water pressure reducing valve but seems like it’s not working properly, as in REDUCING the outflow/water pressure to the house, EVEN MORE when there is VERY LOW INFLOW(pressure coming in(to the reducer) from the MAIN (city water line) as already, which is very common here(in Indonesia) unfortunately , which is exactly WHY I installed a Reducer(bcz pressure from main city water line is constantly UP&DOWN(either too high or too low!!). Is that possible: that EVEN WITH LOW PRESSURE COMING IN the REDUCER FURTHER REDUCES the OUTFLOW EVEN MORE?!?
Seems like I have less pressure (when low pressure coming in) than before, even though I set the Reducer to the Right Pressure-setting (as in as high as possible but not so much to cause damage, when it’s high coming in)?!?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! You'll find that there's NO NEED TO SHOUT at us, we can hear you just fine even in lower case. If you want to improve readability and provide emphasis, there are always line breaks, and the text edit box even has little buttons for **bold** and _italic_ text that are handy for _emphasizing_ certain words. **Please** feel free to [edit] your post to make it a little more readable (bcz u get more nice whn ur nice and spell whole wrds).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the CAPITAL letters, I actually thought it would be useful for those who just want to scan thru my question instead or before reading the whole thing, as I tend to overexpand in trying to explain myself: apparently it had the opposite effect: my bad! But I appreciate the comment as I do the answers and this very helpful website in general..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the incoming pressure is lower than the pressure reducing valve's set point, the valve will still cause some additional pressure loss.

The effect can be reduced to a small degree by using an oversized valve, but the effect can't be eliminated (at least, not with a conventional spring-operated pressure reducing valve).

There might be other things you can do to make your pressure more consistent. One is to install a booster pump: it would take the incoming city pressure and add some additional pressure. Then you'd feed the water into the pressure reducing valve.

Another idea is to build a cistern: an elevated storage tank. It could have the form of an open container or a conventional vessel like a tank water heater or a storage barrel. In any case the vessel could be filled from city water and drained down into your plumbing. The amount of pressure will depend on the elevation of the vessel. It'll be less than the pressure that the city can deliver, but at least it would be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, that’s the impression I got but it’s a bummer because that was the only reason I installed the PRV, is so I wouldn’t have to keep playing with the city main’s inflow valve (opening all the way when low, and reducing when too high)!

Comment: Apparently this PRV I installed is totally useless as it still doesn’t reduce the incoming pressure when very high (6-8bar) coming in, causing some fixtures to leak constantly, and when low pressure coming in(from the city main), it still reduces the pressure even more & too much! So, basically I’m reduced (no punt intended) to being back at just filling up my tank and using my wellpump at all times, to have constant pressure (even though a bit lower than I would prefer when watering the yard, etc..) and not having to constantly adjust the PRV and/or the main valve(incoming)!! Bummer..

Comment: Perhaps part of the original problem(much too high pressure coming in) is that my property is literally at the end of the road..

Comment: @Ben You could confirm the city's high pressure is within spec for your regulator (so as not to damage the regulator) and could disassemble the regulator to check for debris that might cause it to malfunction.

Comment: The PRV I bought online only says “Inlet pressure 16bar”: does that mean it needs to be 16bar MINIMUM for the PRV to work properly?!? Because the City water main Inlet Pressure is never above 8-9 bar here, at the most! Could that be the problem?? Either way, really appreciate all your help , Greg: super nice of you..

Comment: @Ben 16 bar would be quite high for a municipal water service. That's probably the regulator's maximum inlet pressure. If you don't already have a pressure gauge, get one (or two!). I permanently installed a gauge upstream and downstream of the PRV when I was trying to resolve a low pressure problem in my house. It's very helpful when "something just isn't right" to be able to measure and identify just what's going on.

Comment: There is a gauge on the PRV itself, thnks!

Comment: Btw, I mentioned earlier that I m also running a wellwaterpump (pumping water out of an underground rainwater collection tank) on the same water system, to compensate for the frequent lack of pressure(from the city main) : is that ok? Seems to be ..